# php display records not showing

Tags: php

I am trying to show records in php with mysqli. this is my code for php display record which does not gives any error but does  not shows any records as well. insert operation is working but display not working what is missing here ???

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

   movie_name<input type="text" name="movie_name"><br>
   movie_embedded_id<input type="text" name="movie_embedded_id"><br>
   rating_no<input type="text" name="rating_no"><br>
   movie_description<input type="text" name="movie_description"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname="mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

        if(isset($_POST['movie_name']) && $_POST['movie_name'] != "")
            {   
                $sql = "INSERT INTO movies (movie_name, movie_embedded_id, rating_no, movie_description)VALUES ('".$_POST['movie_name']."', '".$_POST['movie_embedded_id']."', '".$_POST['rating_no']."','".$_POST['movie_description']."')";


            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }

        }

$conn->close();


?>


<?php

      if(isset($_POST['movie_name']) && $_POST['movie_name'] != "")
            {
$sql = "select * from movies where movie_id = ".$_GET["id"]."";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>movie_name</th><th>movie_embedded_id</th><th>rating_no</th><th>movie_description</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["movie_name"]. " </td><td>" . $row["movie_embedded_id"]. " </td><td>" . $row["rating_no"]. "</td><td> " . $row["rating_no"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

    }


  ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you checked your sourcecode? maybe he creates the table tags but the $row data is simply empty

Comment: have you debug your code means does $_POST['movie_name'] isset ?

Comment: add else condition also for $_POST['movie_name'] and echo a normal msg

Comment: @Amar Ghodke just try to replace your this query "select * from movies where movie_id = '".$_GET['id']."'"; to this "select * from movies where movie_id = ".$_GET["id"].""

Comment: @Bunker Boy  sorry man, this not worked, just allow me to give full code here, there may you able to find actual problem.

Comment: yeah sure but i think but let me show all the debug values

Comment: what comes under this $result ?

Comment: cut this $conn->close(); and paste at the last of php script

Comment: still not showing records , it is getting annoying to say....

Comment: please show what comes in $result , just print_r($result)

Comment: do i need to add at the end f while loop or after else part ??

Answer (score 0):

let's try this

it will work

```
 <?php

        if(isset($_POST['movie_name']) && $_POST['movie_name'] != "")
            {
$sql = "select * from movies where movie_id = ".$_GET['id'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>movie_name</th><th>movie_embedded_id</th><th>rating_no</th><th>movie_description</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["movie_name"]. " </td><td>" . $row["movie_embedded_id"]. " </td><td>" . $row["rating_no"]. "</td><td> " . $row["rating_no"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

    }
```

Comment: try this 
$sql = "select * from movies where movie_id = ".$_GET['id'];

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$movie = $_POST['movie_name'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

/* I wonder why POST and GET method in the same form : where do $vars come from ? */

echo"[ id is ($id) / movie is ($movie) ]";

/* then if $id isn't empty it should do the trick */

$sql = " SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_id=$id ";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very thank you all for kind responses. here i have figure out my issue.only there is problem when i add id column , extra empty column getting added , don't know why.Kindly review this code for  more secure and optimized.

```
    <div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="movie_name">movie_name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movie_name" name="movie_name" placeholder="Enter movie name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="movie_embedded_id">movie_embedded_id:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movie_embedded_id" name="movie_embedded_id" placeholder="Enter embeded id">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="rating_no">rating_no:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rating_no" name="rating_no" placeholder="Enter rating_no">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="movie_description">rating_no:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movie_description" name="movie_description" placeholder="Enter movie_description">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" >submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
<!--       <th>ID.<th> -->
       <th>movie_name</th>
       <th>movie_embedded_id</th>
       <th>rating_no</th>
       <th>movie_description</th>
       <th>Update</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php  
    include "db.php";
    include "movieinsert.php";

      $result ="select * from movies";
      $get=mysqli_query($conn, $result);

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($get))
        {
    ?>
          <tr>
    <!--      <td><?php //echo "$data[0]"; ?><td> -->
          <td><?php echo "$data[1]"; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo "$data[2]"; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo "$data[3]"; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo "$data[4]"; ?></td>
          <td>
          <a href='mvieupdate.php?id=$data[0]' class="btn btn-info" role="button">Update</a>
          </td>
          </tr>
    <?php 
         }
     ?>
  <tbody>
   </table>
```